# Code Splitting with inital load sequence

Tags: java, gwt, code-splitting

I am working on a GWT project and to increase the processing speed of the project we are using the code splitting technique to split our js file.
Currently, we studied about initial load sequence of project and tried to implement it on our project. When we gave the sequence of class in project xml file there was a class which had multiple runAsync method i.e multiple split points then we got a error **More than one runAsync call is labelled with class com.client.MyHistoryListener**

***Questions to be asked:-***
1.Reason for the error?

2. Is it OK to have multiple runAsync() in a single class will it fragment the class code?
3. What is the correct way of initial load sequence and how it is managed?

   public void onModuleLoad()
   {
       GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onSuccess() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           Resource.INSTANCE.CourseCss().ensureInjected();
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable reason) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println("Fail");
       }
   });
   ```

   }

Comment: We have no Idea what you did so far. Please show what you did so that we need not to use our magic ball.:)